# Plotting a dictionary of DataFrames

Tags: python, dictionary, pandas, matplotlib

I have a `dictionary` of `DataFrames` that I want to use for graphing. This is an example of the data:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(5)
first = pd.DataFrame(columns=range(1,4),data=np.random.rand(3,3), index=range(1,4))
second = pd.DataFrame(columns=range(1,4),data=np.random.rand(3,3)+0.2, index=range(1,4))
third = pd.DataFrame(columns=range(1,4),data=np.random.rand(3,3)+0.05, index=range(1,4))
fourth= pd.DataFrame(columns=range(1,4),data=np.random.rand(3,3)-0.2, index=range(1,4))

d={'frame_1':first,'frame_2':second,'frame_3':third,'frame_4':fourth}

#This is what it looks like
d
    {'frame_1':           1         2         3
 1  0.221993  0.870732  0.206719
 2  0.918611  0.488411  0.611744
 3  0.765908  0.518418  0.296801, 'frame_2':           1         2         3
 1  0.387721  0.280741  0.938440
 2  0.641309  0.358310  1.079937
 3  0.474086  0.614235  0.496080, 'frame_3':           1         2         3
 1  0.678788  0.629838  0.649929
 2  0.315819  0.334686  0.303588
 3  0.377564  0.194164  0.215613, 'frame_4':           1         2         3
 1  0.763931  0.760227 -0.011585
 2 -0.175693  0.004556  0.499844
 3  0.579515 -0.177067  0.377663}
```

Ultimately, I want 9 separate graphs which plot the evolution of each element combination in the `DataFrame` (11,12,13,..) with 1,2,3,4 (relating to 'frame_1', 'frame_2', etc.) as the x-axis. To be clear, this means that the first graph (relating to 11) should contain the values 0.221993, 0.387721, 0.678788 and 0.763931.

Normally I always explain what I've tried to solve the problem myself. However, in this case I haven't got a clue about a possible solution..

Note: the actual dataset are 10x10 `DataFrames` and the `dictionary` contains 75 such DataFrames so I would prefer as much automation as possible.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether I understand what result you want but:

```
for k in d:
    ax = d[k].plot()
```

gives:

[image]
[image]
[image]